# Tomcat jsp parsing

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, captcha

I have a jsp file with the next line:

```
<img src="/captcha"/>
```

And a servlet which is mapped to "`/captcha`".
What is going on (in my opinion): when a user requests the jsp file, Tomcat parses it in one thread and calls the servlet in a new thread.
I want the servlet request to be executed first, before rendering jsp code which is after the `<img srс="/captcha"/>`
Is there a way to do it?

Sorry for awful explanation.

**Update**
Thanks to Elliott Frisch for clarifying how it works.
Let me be more specific. The servlet puts some value to cookie which is requested a bit latter in the jsp `<input type="hidden" name="captcha-id" value="${cookie.captchaId.value}">`. A browser meets this line before the servlet finishes its execution. As a result, I see invalid cookie value. Can you tell me how to handle it?

Comment: There might be a way that you can get the desired functionality. Could you put the captcha id into a session-scoped variable instead of a cookie? If yes, then maybe you could have the JSP wait until that variable is set before sending the final section of the page to the client. We could write demonstration code here, if you want to try that idea.

Comment: Can't you pre-load your captcha as an image via JavaScript? http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/javascript-image-preload

Answer (score 0):

As Elliot has explained how the request flow works: Why are you relying on finding the captcha information in the request - e.g. through an input field/parameter? When you submit the request, including the decoded captcha, you'll get the captcha-cookie anyway and can compare that value with the submitted manually deciphered value. Problem solved, no more relying on obscure request order.

This will only fail in case where people open multiple pages with captchas at the same time and when your captcha always overwrites the cookie. But I guess that this usecase is rare.